# DeepLink in Actions on Google - no longer available?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to implement deeplinking (to an app) in my Actions on Google agent, but can't find any direct reference in the Actions on Google docs: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/intents

However, in the Dialogflow docs I can find a reference to an actions_intent_LINK event: https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/platform-events#permission_request

Plus, I found this page which implements the above actions_intent_LINK event: https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.deeplink.html

When using this event in Dialogflow and in my webhook it doesn't seem to be working as expected as it doesn't give the user a prompt for opening an external app.

Is it possible that the entire DeepLink helper isn't available or updated to Dialogflow v2, since I can't find any relevant docs on https://developers.google.com/actions/ ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to open deeplink urls in google actions v2.
Here is a sample json response that should give a basic card and an option to pen another app via deep link.

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Testing deep linking",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [],
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Testing deep linking"
            }
          },
          {
            "basicCard": {
              "title": "Testing deep linking",
              "image": {
                "url": "optional",
                "accessibilityText": "Testing deep linking"
              },
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "title": "Open other app",
                  "openUrlAction": {
                    "url": "http://deeplinkurl.com"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "imageDisplayOptions": "WHITE"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "source": "Test"
}
```

Google documentation : [OpenUrlAction](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/OpenUrlAction)
IMO the documentation is a bit ambiguous when reading first time around as this is a shared data structure. But it works